# Print of Date() displays time minus 1 hour

Tags: swift, date, timezone, nsdate

I am running an iPhone device with timezone set to load automatically from location, and my location is in CET time.

Now when I print the current date, it shows me the time minus one hour, e.g.

```
// We currently have 17:40 (5:40pm)
print("NOW \(Date())")
// will return:
NOW 2019-01-05 16:40:39 +0000
```

Why doesn't it display correctly in the devices timezone?

Comment: Your code is fine. Look at the output. It's the time in UTC (that's what the +0000 means).

Comment: ahhh got it, thanks for the linking of the post to the other question!